# “TypeError: failed to fetch” from wso2 APIM

Tags: wso2

I am new to WSO2 APIM. I created an API from WSDL which is  http://ws.cdyne.com/phoneverify/phoneverify.asmx?wsdl. When I try to invoke API , I am taking error.

> "TypeError: Failed to fetch "

I am calling API like :

#### call api1

[image: call api1]

#### call api and error

[image: call api and error]

Comment: Open another browser tab and enter the url https://localhost:8243/ and then accept the certificate

Answer (score 1):

This happens mostly due to **SSL-certificate issue**.

Open a new tab in browser and enter the URL: https://localhost:8243

This will download and install the certificate. Then restart the browser and try the API. This should work.

Otherwise, you can directly copy the Curl command generated above your error and import it into Postman application. Postman does not give SSL-certificate issue.

Steps for **Postman**:

1. Open postman application
2. Click on Import, which is at Top-Left of the window besides New button.
3. In Import, select "Pate Raw Text" option
4. Paste the curl command copied from swagger UI and click Import.
5. Click on Send.

Comment: We solved certification error. But now we are taking this error.                                 
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
        <faultcode xmlns:axis2ns19="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">axis2ns19:Client</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Authentication Failure</faultstring>
        <detail>Invalid JWT token. Signature verification failed.</detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: Your JWT token has expired. You need to create a new token. While creating a new token, give -1 in expiry field, so that it will never expire.

Comment: Still taking Invalid JWT token. Signature verification failed.

Comment: The endpoint which you are trying to access using this API, do you have access to that API? If yes, Does it have it's own token? If yes, are you giving correct token?